# selecting element with interpolation

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, string-interpolation

Is it possible to select element with interpolation? 
I have a var with a string

```
inputId = "awesomeInput"
```

and i would like to select input which has ID "awesomeInput". I tried to do it like i would normally do with jquery

```
$("#{inputId}")
```

console.log tells me that something was picked, but any function i try to perform on this object fails. There are no errors, but also no effects. Like this:

```
$("#{inputId}").show()
```

How can I select an element with jquery like this, and than show it?

Answer (score 10):

Given:

```
inputId = "awesomeInput"
```

Then this:

```
$("#{inputId}").show()
```

ends up as:

```
$("awesomeInput").show()
```

and that is trying to find `<awesomeInput>` elements, not `id="awesomeInput"` elements.

The `#` only has special meaning when it is immediately followed by `{` in a double quoted string so the `#` in `"#pancakes"` does not begin an interpolation nor does the first `#` in `"##{x}"`.

You want this:

```
$("##{inputId}").show()
```

The first `#` is just a plain old hashmark, only the `#{...}` part will be replaced during interpolation.